# HTML or Javascript for switching url at a specific time

Tags: javascript, html, url, switch-statement, countdown

I am from Germany, sorry for my English.

I am searching for a simple HTML or Javascript code to switch to another URL at a specific time.

I Run a landing Page which has an offer thats closed at April 16 at ten o clock for example. I need a little Script or code which directs to another url when the öfter will be closed.

I am thankful for any help.

Best regards
Marco

Comment: settimeout to run every second that checks the time and does a location.href change when the timer runs out - beware time zone differences, it runs on the client - use utc time

Comment: you really want to call the function 86,400 times a day?

Comment: You want one or both of two different things — 1) a user _arrives_ at the landing page after the deadline. 2) a user is currently viewing the page and the deadline passes. #1 is best handled on the back-end, #2 would be handled by javascript within the page. Are you looking for a solution for #1, #2, or both?

Answer (score 2):

If the person has the landing page loaded and is viewing it, and you want to send them to a different URL when the offer closes, you can calculate how much time until that happens when they arrive at the landing page then send them to the new URL when that time is reached.

[`setTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout) will run a function after a timer has expired, and that function can change the window.location sending them to the new URL.

When the landing page *loads* get the current time and the time the offer expires:

```
let now = new Date();
let expires = new Date('2021-04-16 22:00:00');
```

Subtracting gives you the number of milliseconds until you reach the expires time, which is convenient because that's what the setTimeout function wants for it's "delay" parameter.

Verbosely, this could look like:

```js
const now = new Date();
const expires = new Date('2021-04-16 22:00:00');
const delay = expires - now;
window.setTimeout(function() {
    window.location = 'https://example.com/';
}, delay);
```

```html
<div>
<p>This is the landing page</p>
</div>
```

This ***does not*** loop waiting for time to expire, as DCR warns in a comment; it just sets a timer, which the browser then takes care of.

All the math could be collapsed without using variables, so it becomes
`window.setTimeout(function() {...etc...}, new Date('2021-04-16 22:00:00') - new Date());`

Answer (score 0):

Here is your script based on your mentioned time. After that specific time, link will be changed automatically.

```
"https://jsfiddle.net/rounak1/2pxLu5df/2/"
```

Comment: If you have a fiddle to demonstrate you should have an actual _link_ to it, not make us copy & paste. You should also have the relevant code _in your answer_, preferably as a _stack snippet_. Link-only answers tend to degrade over time. The answer should also include an explanation of the code and how it solves the problem.

Answer (score 0):

here is the code

```
  let d1 = new Date()
    var d2 = new Date('2021-04-16 22:00:00.00');
    if (d1 > d2) {
        window.location = 'https://www.google.com/'
    }
```

Comment: You are welcome. Please mark it as the correct answer so others can find it easily

Answer (score 0):

I believe that this problem is better handled by your backend that can redirect the user to another page before the page loads since, if you do this in javascript, the page will have to load first.

However, since you want this to be implemented in Javascript you can do something like below:

```
var time = moment("16/04/2021 10:00", "DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm");
var now = new Date();
if (time > now) {
    window.location.replace("replace with your url"); // Without allowing the user to hit the back button
}
```

In the above, `time` stores the datetime when the offer ends in the format enclosed as a string (read about this here: https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/). This is compared to the time `now` to implement a redirect.

Read more about the redirect here: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_redirect_webpage.asp

The above requires the usage of the moment.js library which you can find here: https://momentjs.com/